# How to solve timeout termination issue (time limit exceeded) while using for loop on javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance

This is the link to the question below this paragraph. To sum it up:

- Given a number `n`,
- We are to find the sum of all the multiples of 3 and 5 below `n`.
- There may be `t` numbers in the input,
- Numbers are separated by linebreaks.

I am getting the correct answer but receiving a `timeout termination error` due to `time limit exceeded` for 2 out of 6 test cases and the other 4 are passing.

Question:
`https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler001/problem?isFullScreen=true`

This is my solution which I tried where I created a var using `let` (also tried using `var`) to store my total value in the variable `total`. I run 2 for loops. For the first `for` loop, I divide `n/3` for my total number of iterations and then for my 2nd one, I divide `n/5` for my total number of iterations and exclude all multiples of 3 to prevent duplicates. During each iteration, I increment the value of `total` by the value of `x`.

```js
function main() {
  var t = parseInt(readLine());
  for (var a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++) {
    var n = parseInt(readLine());
    //added my code here
    let total = 0;
    for (let x = 0; x < n / 3; x++) {
      total += 3 * x;
    }
    for (let x = 0; x < n / 5; x++) {
      if (x % 3 !== 0) total += 5 * x;
    }
    console.log(total)
  }
}
```

I also tried reducing the number of times multiplication is performed by moving it to after the `for` loops are complete but still faced the same timeout issue:

```js
function main() {
  var t = parseInt(readLine());
  for (var a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++) {
    var n = parseInt(readLine());
    //added my code here
    let total = 0;
    let totalTemp = 0
    for (let x = 0; x < n / 3; x++) {
      total += x;
    }
    for (let x = 0; x < n / 5; x++) {
      if (x % 3 !== 0) totalTemp += x;
    }
    total = totalTemp * 5 + total * 3;
    console.log(total);
  }
}
```

Comment: The purpose of this question is to see if you can figure out how to solve it *without* a brute force loop.   As a simplified starting point, think about how to simplify the math involved in summing up all the multiples of 3 below `n` -- it's going to be 3*1 + 3*2 + 3*3 + .... -- and see if you can figure out a way to do that math without looping over the list.

Comment: [sum of integers formula](https://www.cuemath.com/sum-of-integers-formula/). This is probably the math you learned in high school that you thought you would never need in real life.

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like this
`3 + 3*2 + 3*3 + ... = 3*(1+2+3+...) = 3*(n*(n+1)2)`
same for 5

now you double count some multiples , workaround is to subtract multiples of 15

```java
int sumOfMultiples(int k, int N) {
        int n = (N-1) / k;
        return k * n * (n+1) / 2;
    }
}
sumOfMultiples(3, N) + sumOfMultiples(5, N) - sumOfMultiples(15, N); // answer
```

Note : If you can count multiples two times u can skip `- sumOfMultiples(15, N)`

Comment: This does not appear to be JavaScript here.